# Can't find Sublime Text 3's "Default" folder in <data_path>/Packages/ folder using Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, sublime-text-3

I have Sublime Text 3(ST3) installed on Windows 7.

I click "Preferences > Settings - Default" in ST3's menu.

A file named Preferences.sublime-settings opens up in ST3. Fine. In ST3's title bar, it indicates that this preferences file is located in C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Default\

Now, the problem is, if I open Windows Explorer and navigate to C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages, there's no directory named "Default"

So why can't I see this directory? And where is the "Preferences > Settings - Default" file actually located and if it's actually in another folder, why would it show a different path in ST3'a title bar?

Comment: Your question has been answered.  It is not a candidate to be deleted.  Vandalizing your own question isn’t something you should do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike ST2, which contained everything in the `Packages` directory, packages in ST3 are located in zipped `.sublime-package` files in the `Installed Packages` directory (in `AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3`). Sublime is internally configured to display a file contained in a `.sublime-package` archive as originating in `Packages`, even though it physically may not be there on the disk.

If you want to access the files in a `.sublime-package` file (which I wouldn't recommend unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing), install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) package through Package Control, and utilize the commands in the Command Palette.